# What is the controller syntax for sorting multiple MvcContrib Grids?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I can't quite figure out the syntax for sorting multiple MvcContrib grids.  I know the recommendation from Jeremy Skinner [here](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/workitem/7032) is to use the Bind attribute but I just can't get it right.

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index([Bind](Prefix="grid1")GridSortOptions sort)\\how do I reference the prefix of my second grid?
{
  ViewData["sort"] = sort;
  var products = _productService.GetAllProducts();
  var categories = _categoryService.GetAllCategories();

  //Here is where I am stuck
  if(sort.Column != null)
   {
     products = products.OrderBy(sort.Column, sort.Direction);
     //how do I reference the sort columns of my second grid?
   }

  var model = new ContainerModel
              {
                Products = products,
                Categories = categories
              };

  return View(model);
}
```

I guess I really don't understand everything about the Bind attribute.  I tried adding a second GridSortOptions argument but that was not successful.

Here are my views if this helps.

```
.Sort((GridSortOptions)ViewData["sort"], "grid1")//Grid 1
.Sort((GridSortOptions)ViewData["sort"], "grid2")//Grid 2
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Any luck with this yet? I'm having similar woes.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem from my post:

[MVCContrib Grid - Sort(GridSortOptions, prefix) not generating links for sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518581/mvccontrib-grid-sortgridsortoptions-prefix-not-generating-links-for-sorting)

It is possible that the default binder is not pre-populating your parameters and so your GridSortoptions are probably null which means no links ultimately.

Also, just create a second GridSortOptions parameter for the second grid and use that in the call to Sort().

Comment: It might be helpful for others to know that for this to work, you need to set a prefix for each of the grids to be sorted on the same page. As in: `.Sort((GridSortOptions)ViewData["fooSort"],"foo")`