# MVCContrib Grid - Sort(GridSortOptions, prefix) not generating links for sorting

Tags: mvccontrib-grid

I'm trying to use two grids in the same page and following what I found here:

http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/workitem/7032

Has anyone else had a problem with the Sort() method not generating links?

The sorting was working before but it was sorting both grids the same way. The only thing I have changed is added the Bind attributes as the page above instructs and added the prefix to the call to Sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the mvccontrib grid code checks if the SortOptions has been populated and if the column is sortable. If false, no links.

Apparently the BindAttribute causes the default model binder to NOT populate the paramter objects first time through which in this case meant my GridSortOption parameters were both null.